# What is NPM and why do I need it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

In the past, I made some websites with notepad for example, so we must create a folder TREE and put into it a .htm file, and some folderS with stuff like Javascript, css ...

Maybe I don't understand what NPM really brings, because It seems to do the same thing but automated it ... is it just that ?

For example, why not just unpack a frameworks (e.g. Bootstrap or Kube) without use of NPM and so have folders ready to use ?

Help me to understand please because I'm near the crazy state with all this stuff ...

Comment: NPM is used to manage dependencies for packages. If you were to unpack a framework and use it outside NPM, you would have to do this every time you want to update the framework. NPM does this for you. You always know what version you're on, and you can limit a dependency to a specific major/minor/patch version.

Comment: This link might help you: www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/

Comment: I sadly relate to this question, from when I used to write (now build) websites 20+ years ago. I could just cramp in frontend and backend code (terms not used back then?) in a notepad file. I wasn't thinking separately in php, javascript or HTML. They all meshed together, I just have to know when to write what. Heck, I won't even bother separating codes into folders!  But things quickly get complicated over the years. People write codes on top of one another, while each making changes on their own. Things quickly grown to a web of unmanageable mess needing software to "install"

Answer (score 112):

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) is a package manager for Node.js with hundreds of thousands of packages. Although it does create some of your directory structure/organization, this is not the main purpose.

The main goal, as you touched upon, is automated dependency and package management. This means that you can [specify all of your project's dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) inside your `package.json` file, then any time you (or anyone else) needs to get started with your project they can just run `npm install` and immediately have all of the dependencies installed. On top of this, it is also possible to specify what **versions** your project depends upon to prevent updates from breaking your project.

It is definitely possible to manually download your libraries, copy them into the correct directories, and use them that way. However, as your project (and list of dependencies) grows, this will quickly become time-consuming and messy. It also makes collaborating and sharing your project that much more difficult.

Hopefully this makes it more clear what the purpose of npm is. As a Javascript developer (both client-side and server-side), npm is an indispensable tool in my workflow.

Comment: how far can we compare this with Maven.?? (It is just for understanding purpose. Not meant to actually compare to different techniques)

Comment: @Jakemmarsh what is the main aim of npm and bower and why it uses cli please help as i am beginer to learn it

Comment: @Praveen I know that you asked this long time ago. But for others that may have the same question I would say the are kind of serve kind of the same purpose. The difference is that Maven is to manage Java applications and NPM is to manage Javascript applications.

Comment: @Praveen Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388824/is-maven-similar-to-npm

Answer (score 5):

NPM basically is the package manager for node. It helps with installing various packages and resolving their various dependencies. It greatly helps with your Node development. NPM helps you install the various modules you need for your web development and not just given you a whole bunch of features you might never need.

Answer (score 4):

NPM is a Node Package Manager and it's use for

- it is an online repository for the publishing of open-source Node.js
  projects.
- Command line utility to install Node.js packages, do version
  management and dependency management of Node.js packages.

Answer (score 1):

NPM is a node package manager. It is basically used for managing dependencies of various server side dependencies.

We can manages our server side dependencies manually as well but once our project's dependencies grow it becomes difficult to install and manage.

By using NPM it becomes easy, we just need to install NPM once for all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

npm is Node's package manager. It's a repository of hundreds of thousands of useful pieces of code that you may want to integrate with your Node project.

npm also has a command line tool that lets us easily install, manage and run projects.

Use npm to . . .

- Adapt packages of code for your apps, or incorporate packages as they are.
- Download standalone tools you can use right away.
- Run packages without downloading using npx.
- Share code with any npm user, anywhere.
- Restrict code to specific developers.
- Create Orgs (organizations) to coordinate package maintenance, coding, and developers.
- Form virtual teams by using Orgs.
- Manage multiple versions of code and code dependencies.
- Update applications easily when underlying code is updated.
- Discover multiple ways to solve the same puzzle.
- Find other developers who are working on similar problems and projects.

READ MORE [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm/)

Answer (score 0):

It stands for **Node Package Manager**

Comment: & you don't need it, but when you opt into dealing with the absurdly overcomplicated JS libraries of today, there's a small chance you might want something like it so you don't see the immense mess. Haven't found a need for it myself yet.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik If you haven't found a need for a package manager, have fun updating dependencies and communicating to others what needs to be installed.

Comment: That's kind of my point. I haven't found a need for a pile of JavaScript so immense as to require deps.

Comment: No. See: https://github.com/npm/cli#is-npm-an-acronym-for-node-package-manager