# Installing modules in node

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to install a module in node and i have never done this before. 
I have downloaded the busboy module which is a folder named "busboy-master" coming with three subfolders and a few files. I have put the "busboy-master" folder inside C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules

In a node command prompt I type: `npm install busboy`

At this point the console seems to be doing stuff but doesn't seem to give either error or confirmation.

Anyway, when I run my javascript I still get an error on the line that says: `var busboy = require('busboy');`

and the error from the console is : `Error, cannot find module busboy.`

I have also tried to put the busboy-master folder in this directory without luck: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules.

I have never installed a module before and I can't find any walkthroughs on how to do this. Is there any steps I am missing or something more or different I should be doing?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is NPM and why do I need it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930370/what-is-npm-and-why-do-i-need-it)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to install npm.

**1.Local**

**npm install npm_name**

If you want to use it on the specific application. You just go to root directory & use above command.

Scope for this npm is for that application only. If you want to use it on other application, you need to install again.

If use install locally, installation path will be with in same folder, inside the **node_modules** folder

**2. Global**

**npm install -g npm-name**

If you want to use it globally.Suppose you want to use one npm in every application. If you install globally, you don't need to install it again.

Ex. We will use express npm in every application. So we install globally & use it in every application.

Installation path of folder will be C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the absolute bare-essential basics of node and npm. Flex your google-muscles. Here, i'll get you started. I googled "what is npm" and found this [great introduction](https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/) that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the module busboy completely from your node module. Just go to node module directory and give command

```
npm install busboy
```

And in your js file write

```
 var busboy = require('busboy');
```

It will work for sure.